# Is there a word that would mean increaser (like a noun)?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I want a noun (a thing not a person).

Consider an electric engine. The 'increaser' would be a knob which would increase the flow of electricity and make the engine give more power. A better way to describe that would be an 'increaser' that creates an electric field which causes the engine to work better (I don't know if that's possible). That effectively changes the environment so the target does more.

Here are a couple of words I considered but rejected:

- *augmenter*: but that seems to imply something is added on as opposed to make the original item more; and
- *booster*: closer to the idea I am trying to say, but it sounds temporary and its effect could be by way of something other than increasing the original item.  For example a rocket booster is a different smaller rocket which boosts the main rocket, it is not causing the main rocket to be larger and more powerful.

Comment: Yes, this is unclear. Do you want a noun (label for a person) that makes something bigger? How can you do any of what you're asking, without changing it?

Comment: I suppose [Embiggen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embiggen) (v) could be further extended to embiggener (n)

Comment: In the days of film, a photographer would use an **enlarger** to make prints larger.

Comment: @Mitch, I guess that is what my problem is.  The idea is difficult to describe in a way that makes sense.  I do want a noun (a thing not a person).

Another example would be something like an electric engine.  The 'increaser' would be a knob which would increase the flow of electricity and make the engine give more power.

A better way to describe that would be an 'increaser' that creates an electric field which causes the engine to work better (I don't know if that's  possible).  That effectively changing the environment so the target does more.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth and (at)Alok  Those are somewhat close to the idea but both imply an increase in size and not function.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. I've edited your question to incorporate the good example you gave in comments, and also reworded the question itself for clarity and presentation. Please feel free to [edit] it further, or to roll back the changes.

Answer (score 1):

**[enhancer](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enhancer?a=british)** might fit:

> something that is used to strengthen or improve the quality of something. Enhancer is usually used as a combining form:
>
> - *Music can be a **mood** enhancer.*
> - *I don't like to use artificial **flavour**-enhancers in my cooking.*

([Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enhancer?a=british))

Answer (score -1):

**Increment** might work here:

> Increment (noun)
>   1: the action or process of increasing especially in quantity or value :  enlargement
>   2: 
>    A:  something gained or added
>    B:  one of a series of regular consecutive additions
>   C:  a minute increase in quantity

I often use **increment** as a verb, whether right or wrong, however you could nounify further by using **incrementer**.

Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/increment

Answer (score -1):

My first thought was *catalyst*, but I think that is more of a trigger, and you want something that provides a more permanent increase. [Stimulus](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stimulus) implies a long term effect, or similarly *impetus*.

However, I get the feeling these are too abstract, and you want a word for a button or knob that provides the stimulus. I'm not sure there is a general word, as there are specific words for these given the particular context, such as accelerator, booster or amplifier.